# Formatear texto HTML en copy/paste pero respetando los saltos de línea con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy tratando de formatear cualquier texto pero, respetando los posibles saltos de línea (break lines). Para ello uso el siguiente código:

```js
function remove_tags(html)  {
            var html = html.replace("<br>","||br||"),
                tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
            tmp.innerHTML = html;
            html = tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
            var returned = html.replace("||br||","<br>");  
            
            document.getElementById('pasted-text').innerHTML = returned;
        }

        document.getElementById('pasted-text').addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
            var clipboardData, pastedData;

            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            
            clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
            pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
            
            remove_tags(pastedData);
        });
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="pasted-text">

</div>
```

En este caso me está copiando y pegando el texto HTML al hacer copy o <kbd>ctrl + C</kbd> pero cuando lo pego en el DIV con 'contenteditable', me lo pega entero formateándolo pero, no me respeta los saltos de línea haciendo que esté en un único bloque de texto todo.

¿Qué falla para que no pegue el texto con saltos de línea?

https://jsfiddle.net/wz2eq13j/

Comment: Deberías agregar también el HTML necesario

Comment: No se si te he entendido, es decir, no está capturando y pegando el 'returned'? Voy a corregir el post inicial ya que me equivoqué.

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código en un snippet de la página y funciona correctamente

Comment: ¿Aplica los espacios de línea? He probado en dos documentos html distintos para descartar eso y no lo hace.

Comment: Pues probé cogiendo un pedazo de texto de una app web mia y lo pegue y cogió todos los espacios, no debería de funcionar asi?

Comment: Y si reemplazas los <br> por \n||br||

Comment: Tiene que funcionar de la siguiente manera. Copias cualquier cosa de una web que tenga negritas, alguna imagen, saltos de línea... etc. Pegas en el div editable con esta funcionalidad y te debe pegar SOLO el texto respetando los saltos de línea ya que debería añadir los BR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes 2 problemas en el código:

En el caso de las tabulaciones, se pueden interpretar como espacios en blanco, que en lenguaje html (que es lo que insertas dentro del div) se escribe `&nbsp;`, por tanto debes cambiar los espacios por su equivalente en html.

Luego la función `replace()` no es la mas indicada para remplazar caracteres en este caso, te recomiendo usar `split()` y `join()`, de esa forma puedes reemplazar todas las ocurrencias.

Aquí esta el código funcionando, le pese un textarea para mostrar el texto que se esta pegando en el div y ver las diferencias.

```js
function remove_tags(html)  {
            var html = html.split("<br>").join("||br||").split(" ").join("&nbsp;"),
                tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
            tmp.innerHTML = html;
            html = tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
            var returned = html.split("||br||").join("<br>");  
            
            document.getElementById('pasted-text').innerHTML = returned;
            //esta linea esta demas, la puse para mostrar el codigo copiado en el textarea
            document.getElementById('pasted-text2').value = returned;
        }

        document.getElementById('pasted-text').addEventListener("paste", function(e) {
            var clipboardData, pastedData;

            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            
            clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
            pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
            
            remove_tags(pastedData);
        });
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="pasted-text">

</div>
<!-- para ver las diferencias -->
<textarea id="pasted-text2" rows=10 cols=50></textarea>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Gracias, está bastante bien pero tengo un problema. Estoy copiando un texto de un word, y todos los espacios los ha reemplazado por &nbsp y los saltos de línea no me los aplica. Este funcionamiento es normal?

Comment: ¿buscas que reconozca tanto los `<br>` como los saltos de texto normal? en ese caso debes capturar los `"\n"` también, cambia la linea `var html = html.split("<br>").join("||br||");` por `var html = html.split("<br>").join("||br||").split("\n").join("||br||")`

Comment: Ahora está perfecto. Gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda!

Comment: @Qadesh, de nada, que tengas buen día.